# Dynamically add bootstrap rows using modulo

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, modulo

I a trying to dynamically add rows and populate them with 3 `col-sm-4` using a modulo against the number of objects in a returned object from a function.

**Code**:

```
 function formatSeriesCard(series) {
    var card = "";

    console.log(countProperties(series));

    for (var i=0; i < countProperties(series); i++) {

    if (i % 3 == 0 ) {
        card += "<div class=\"row\">";
    }

    card += "<div class='col-sm-4' data-id="+i+">";
    card +=     "<div class='action-box'>";
    card +=         "<h4>" + '"' + series.name + '"' + "</h4>";
    card +=         "<p>";
```

Instead I'm getting each row nested within the previous. Thinking I need to test for the first one and last one. Thanks.

Comment: where are you closing your row div ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something like what you want

**Bootply** : http://www.bootply.com/2xnJBpyVsS

**JS** :

```
var wantedcol=14;

var mycol='<div class="col-xs-4">mycol</div>';

var startRowLabel="<div class='row'>";
var endRowLabel="</div>";
var start = "";
var end="";

var toAppend="";
for(var i=0; i<wantedcol; i++){
  start="";
  if(i%3==0 || i==0){
    start=startRowLabel;
  }
  end="";
  if(i!=0 && (i%3==2 || i==wantedcol-1)){
    end=endRowLabel;
  }
  console.log(start+mycol+end);
  toAppend+=start+mycol+end;

}

$('.container').append(toAppend);
```

**HTML**:

```
<div class="container"></div>
```

**Comment** :

*You just have to take care about when you have to insert the `div.row` opening and closing tags*